# SQL : Increment a new column whenever there is a multiple of 5 else dont

Tags: mysql, sql, row, increment, multiple-select-query

I came across this question in a round of interview. A table has the following column.

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 20 |
| 22 |
| 23 |
| 24 |
| 26 |

The question is to create a new column that starts with '1' and increments on the next ID whenever there is a multiple of 5. So the expected output is

| ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 |
| 15 | 2 |
| 16 | 3 |
| 17 | 3 |
| 18 | 3 |
| 19 | 3 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 22 | 4 |
| 23 | 4 |
| 24 | 4 |
| 26 | 4 |

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two window functions: `LAG()` and `SUM()`. For example:

```
select id, 
  1 + sum(case when lid % 5 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id) as v
from (
  select *, lag(id) over(order by id) as lid from t
) x
order by id
```

Result:

```
 id  v 
 --  - 
 1   1 
 2   1 
 3   1 
 4   1 
 5   1 
 6   2 
 7   2 
 8   2 
 9   2 
 11  2 
 12  2 
 13  2 
 14  2 
 15  2 
 16  3 
 17  3 
 18  3 
 19  3 
 20  3 
 22  4 
 23  4 
 24  4 
 26  4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwcrvGMi2JVNjKUGqnMHUf/1).

Comment: 2 should be given after 5 and not to 5.

Comment: Didn't notice that detail. See updated solution.

Comment: *See running example at DB Fiddle.* The question is MySQL-tagged, why the fiddle is made for PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Akina at least they provided one

Comment: @Akina It was a theoretical question, only tagged as SQL when I responded.

Comment: Tags list was altered? Ok.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwcrvGMi2JVNjKUGqnMHUf/2 seems to be more simple

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 5+ you may use, for example

```
SELECT id, (@result := COALESCE( @result + !(id % 5), 1 )) - !(id % 5) result
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @result := NULL) init_variable
ORDER BY id
```

For MySQL 8+ use

```
SELECT id, 1 + SUM(!(id % 5)) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) resuls
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       1 + sum( (id % 5) = 0 ) over (order by id) - (id % 5 = 0)
from t
order by id;
```

What is the logic here?  Calculate the cumulative sum of "5"s up to this row.  Then subtract out the value on this row, because the increment takes effect on the next row.

It is also tempting to write this using a window frame clause, but that ends up being a wee bit more complicated because the first value is `NULL`:

```
select t.*,
       1 + coalesce(sum( (id % 5) = 0 ) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)
from t
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1656179810ebc06e349dd61658831383) is a db<>fiddle.